# Network package changes behaviour of summary for character vectors, breaking summary.data.frame (all values are printed, preceded by NULL: )

Tags: r, statnet

After loading the `network` package, I have an issue with the `summary.data.frame` function: if a column of class `"character"` is present, instead of the usual output, summary will print the values from **all** rows, prepended by `NULL:`. Here's a toy example:

```
test <- data.frame(a=c("some", "char", "vector", "with", 
                       "many", "many", "words"),
                   b=1:7, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Expected behaviour

summary(test$a)

##    Length     Class      Mode 
##         7 character character

summary(test)

##       a                   b      
##  Length:7           Min.   :1.0  
##  Class :character   1st Qu.:2.5  
##  Mode  :character   Median :4.0  
##                     Mean   :4.0  
##                     3rd Qu.:5.5  
##                     Max.   :7.0

library("network")

## network: Classes for Relational Data
## Version 1.13.0 created on 2015-08-31.
## ...

# Behavior after loading network:

summary(test$a)

##   char   many   some vector   with  words 
##      1      2      1      1      1      1

summary(test)

##     a                b      
##  NULL:some     Min.   :1.0  
##  NULL:char     1st Qu.:2.5  
##  NULL:vector   Median :4.0  
##  NULL:with     Mean   :4.0  
##  NULL:many     3rd Qu.:5.5  
##  NULL:many     Max.   :7.0  
##  NULL:words
```

Note that the output includes all elements of the character vector, including repetitions, so you get 1000 lines of summary for 1000 rows,
which renders the summary function unusable.
This behavior stays after detaching the network package, until restart of a new R session.

**What goes wrong**: normally `UseMethod("summary")` for character vectors calls `summary.default`, which produces the normal output, which has `names`.

```
summary.default(test$a)

##    Length     Class      Mode 
##         7 character character

names(summary.default(test$a))

## [1] "Length" "Class"  "Mode"
```

The network package defines a `summary.character` function, which simply adds a `"summary.character"` class to the character object, such that its print calls `network::print.summary.character`, which produces the table with up to `10` most frequent values. The object itself is unchanged, so its `names` is `NULL`.

```
summary.character

## function (object, ...) 
## {
##     class(object) <- c("summary.character", class(object))
##     object
## }
## <environment: namespace:network>

summary.character(test$a)

##   char   many   some vector   with  words 
##      1      2      1      1      1      1

names(summary.character(test$a))

## NULL

class(summary.character(test$a))

## [1] "summary.character" "character"

length(summary.character(test$a))

## [1] 7

as.character(summary.character(test$a))

## [1] "some"   "char"   "vector" "with"   "many"   "many"   "words"
```

The trouble comes from these three lines in `summary.data.frame`:

```
        sms <- format(sms, digits = digits)
        lbs <- format(names(sms))
        sms <- paste0(lbs, ":", sms, "  ")
```

It's inside a `for` loop over columns, where `sms` is the output of `summary` for the current column. For the output of `summary.character`, `sms` is actually the whole column, and `names(sms)` is `NULL`, hence the issue.

The core cause of the problem is that `summary.character` returns the original object, instead of its summary representation, which is delegated to `print.summary.character`. `summary.data.frame` just pastes it with the other summaries, dumping the whole column.

Any idea on how to fix this without diving into the sources of `network` would be very appreciated.

Comment: I am not getting the same output with `summary(test$a)` using `R 3.4.0`

Comment: Have you tried restarting R and cleaning out your environment as in `rm(list=ls())`, then cut/paste from your SO post ?  I am just wondering if there is something else going on.   I don't get your result and I am using 3.3.2 on OS X.

Comment: @steveb indeed, if I restart with `R --no-restore-data` the issue disappears

Comment: @ggll You have at least two options, start with a clean environment or restart R with the "restored" environment and debug.  If you choose the latter option, you may want to use `str(test)` to see what types are really used and compare between both the "no-restored" and "restored" environments.  The things that come to mind are any of the following: (*) the `test` data frames are not really the same between restored/non-restored (*) the `summary` function may have been overridden, or obviously (*) something else that needs more info.

Comment: If you figure out what caused this, please provide the solution on this post.  You might be surprised how many people run into something like this.

Comment: @ggll I was able to reproduce your error when using the `network` library.  Even when I use `base::summary` or `base::summary.data.frame`.  It sounds like the `summary` package is doing something it shouldn't.

Comment: @ggll One thought I had is to not "pollute" your space in R, you could call `network` functions without loading the library, as in `network::<function_name>(...)`.  This is NOT ideal, and I am not sure it will work but if it does work, it may be a temporary workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a turnaround this, unfortunately it involves "polluting" R namespace a bit more (to cite @steveb's comments), by defining a function `format.summary.character` that restores the expected behavior of the code inside `summary.data.frame`. The function is inspired by `format.factor`:

```
format.summary.character <- function(x, ...) {
    s <- summary.default(as.character(x), ...)
    format(structure(as.character(s), names = names(s), dim = dim(s), 
                     dimnames = dimnames(s)), ...)
}
```

After defining this function, the output of summary for character vector is still controlled by `summary.character`, but the output for `summary.data.frame` goes back to normal.

```
summary(test$a) # still calling summary.character

##   char   many   some vector   with  words 
##      1      2      1      1      1      1

summary(test)   # back to normal

##       a                   b      
##  Length:7           Min.   :1.0  
##  Class :character   1st Qu.:2.5  
##  Mode  :character   Median :4.0  
##                     Mean   :4.0  
##                     3rd Qu.:5.5  
##                     Max.   :7.0  
##
```